# Dart Mirrors Not Supported When Compiling Using arm64v8/dart Docker Image

Tags: docker, dart, arm64, raspberry-pi4

Have a pure Dart server app which is currently using 'dart:mirrors' in a class to do a bit of light reflection work at runtime. The server app compiles and runs absolutely fine in development Ubuntu machine with x86 architecture but, the same server app fails to compile as part of a Docker build on an Ubuntu Raspberry pi 4 using latest `arm64v8/dart:stable` Docker Image.

Docker build error:

```
---> Running in e4bdea430736\n\u001b[91merror: import of dart:mirrors is not supported in the current Dart runtime\n\u001b[0m\u001b[91mError: AOT compilation failed\n\u001b[0m\u001b[91mGenerating AOT snapshot failed!\u001b[0m\u001b[91m\n\u001b[0m
```

Is 'dart:mirrors' not supported in current arm64 architecture version of Dart? Or could the issue be something else?

**NOTE: The server app is pure Dart code (i.e. there is no Flutter code being used at all either directly or indirectly via dependencies - as far as I can see).**

--- UPDATE ---

Dockerfile compile instructions:

```
FROM arm64v8/dart:stable AS build
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN dart pub get
RUN dart pub upgrade
RUN dart pub outdated
RUN dart compile exe /example.com/example_api/bin/server.dart -o /example.com/example_api/bin/server
```

Comment: What command are you using to compile the dart code?

Comment: @VladimirGadzhov see update in post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-contained executables (exe) has limitations. One of them is No support for **dart:mirrors** and **dart:developer**

Please check the [documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-compile#exe), and you may try the JIT snapshot or the Kernel subcommands, since they do not have that limitation.

Comment: Using `RUN dart compile jit-snapshot` resolves the `dart:mirrors` not supported issue but when trying to compile the code this way it then expects to actually run the code there and then which would mean needing a connection to resources the app needs (Redis data store with authentication in this case). I will accept your answer as it answers the post's question but I am thinking it will be best for me to go back to the drawing board and re-design and implement the server app to avoid using `dart:mirrors` in the first place (which should be possible with a bit of refactoring).